# Help me on nsdictionary question

Tags: iphone, ios4

When i run my below code it shows me a error like below

warning: 'NSMutableDictionary' may not respond to '-setObject:forKey:forKey:'

what is the problem in my code.

```
myNumberOfPlayers = players;

myDifficultyLevel = difficulty;

myDuration = duration;

myExcerciseId = excerciseId;

NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [ myDictionary setObject:players forKey:players  forKey:@"no_of_players"];
    [ myDictionary setObject:difficulty forKey:@"difficulty_level"];
    [ myDictionary setObject:duration forKey:@"duration_excercise"];
    [ myDictionary setObject:excerciseId forKey:@"Excercise_id"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
[myDictionary setObject:players forKey:@"no_of_players"];
```

instead of

```
[myDictionary setObject:players forKey:players  forKey:@"no_of_players"];
```

Answer (score 3):

NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
[ myDictionary setObject:players forKey:@"no_of_players"];
[ myDictionary setObject:difficulty forKey:@"difficulty_level"];
[ myDictionary setObject:duration forKey:@"duration_excercise"];
[ myDictionary setObject:excerciseId forKey:@"Excercise_id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a method that does not exist.
You should try this:

```
[ myDictionary setObject:players forKey:players ]
```

or this

```
[ myDictionary setObject:players forKey:@"no_of_players"]
```

I bet that the second choice is the right one. Probably there's a typo in your code and you accidentally duplicated the `players` variable.

A dictionary can set an object for a determined key. It makes no sense to set an object giving two different keys in the same call.

Answer (score 2):

This code must look like

```
 NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myDictionary setObject:players forKey:@"no_of_players"];//you cant call for key two time.
[myDictionary setObject:difficulty forKey:@"difficulty_level"];
[myDictionary setObject:duration forKey:@"duration_excercise"];
[myDictionary setObject:excerciseId forKey:@"Excercise_id"];
```